# deep module require of non standard module structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, require

Ok. So what I am trying to do is basically have 1 module with a bunch of folders in it as follows

```
publicmodulename
  |-lib
      |–index.js
      |-f1
          |-index.js
      |-f2
          |-index.js
      |-f3
          |-index.js
```

and all I want to be able to do is tell npm that if the user requires this package (call it publicmodulename for now) then it will behave normally

granted I have my `main` key in my `package.json` set to `"./lib/index.js"`

```
require('publicmodulename'); // runs lib/index.js
```

but if a user requires a subfolder

```
require('publicmodulename/f1');
```

that it will not error. I tried this and it does not seem to work out too well. Anyone have any suggestions?